# Best practice python syntax using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

First time ever posting here, please be gentle, not even sure I have all the terminology correct. I couldn't find anything related.

I'm trying to add a find_element_by_css_selector, and getting a deprecated warning. I'd like to use the proper syntax for upcoming versions (find_element(By.Css_SELECTOR)) however 'By.' isn't recognized as a valid call?

I've tried using the syntax suggested from the terminal log (by=By.CSS_SELECTOR) in which case 'by=' is recognized, but running that returns NameError: name 'By.' is not defined

```
elem_list= browser.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR("div.a-section.a-spacing-medium._octopus-search-result-card_style_apbSearchResultsContainer__bCqjb"))
```

I've also tried

```
elem_list= browser.find_element(By.CSS_SEECTOR, "div.a-section.a-spacing-medium._octopus-search-result-card_style_apbSearchResultsContainer__bCqjb")
```

I tried updating Selenium to see if I was missing something and got the same errors both times.

Again, this is all pretty new to me and I created a StackExchange account just to try and figure this out.

EDIT: Thank you, answer has been selected. Cheers!

Comment: Also add the import statements you have used in the question.

Comment: The error is about the "by" in `By.CSS_SELECTOR`, not the `by=`. You need to import things that you did not define yourself.

Comment: There are a couple of things which can be improved/optimized. Among them which error message do you want to address through this question? Update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to import `By` from `selenium.webdriver.common.by`

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Here is how to implement `By` in code

```py
elem_list = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR(
    "div.a-section.a-spacing-medium._octopus-search-result-card_style_apbSearchResultsContainer__bCqjb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the import statements below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

If my answer helps you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer and also upvote